# limit number of groups from carddav.address.yahoo.com on iOS AddressBook?

Tags: ios, yahoo, addressbook

Is there a limit on carddav.address.yahoo.com in iOS AddressBook ?
In my iOS address book, I've address groups from iCloud, 2 from Exchange, 2 from carddav.address.yahoo.com.  All working fine.

But when I tried adding a 3rd one from carddav.address.yahoo.com (from a different yahoo id), iOS address-book silently ignore the 3rd one so I can't search any address book entries for the 3rd one.

Is this problem came from Yahoo or iOS ?

Thanks much.